# Can I automatically flow two font styles in a Pango Cairo Layout?

Tags: cairo, pango

I want two paragraphs with different styles of text, one above the other. This is the quickest way to describe it:

```
<p style="font-size: 20pt">Para 1</p><p style="font-size: 10pt">Para 2</p>
```

I am setting line-wrap on both, so I do not know what height the first will be until run-time. If I have many lines in paragraph 1, I will want to move paragraph 2 down. If I have one line in paragraph one, I want to move paragraph 2 up. As HTML would behave.

But it appears I can only set one font style per Layout using `pango_layout_set_font_description(PangoLayout *, PangoFontDescription *)`.

1. Does this mean I need to use 2 layouts?
2. If so, how do I get the second layout to appear immediately under the second one? Do I need to use `pango_layout_get_height(PangoLayout *)` and move the second layout accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible. If you were using pango_parse_markup(), you could use something like '<span font="Sans 12">foo</span><span font="Sans 16">bar</span>'. If you don't want to use pango_parse_markup(), look at PangoAttrType and PangoAttrList. However, I don't have any example for them. Looks like you need pango_attr_list_new(), pango_attr_list_insert(), pango_attr_size_new() and pango_layout_set_attributes(). (Set the start_index and end_index in PangoAttribute!)

Of course, you could also use multiple layouts, but it might be easier to make pango figure out the needed magic for you.

Comment: I'm afraid the project I needed this for has been cancelled so I can't test this. I'll give you an upvote but I can't mark this as correct, sorry.